# Trying to pass pipeline from a PowerShell function

Tags: powershell-3.0

Here's the simple code:

```bsh
function getcomputer() {
  if (($a.Length) -eq "1") {
    if (-not(Test-Path "C:\users\ka1\documents\listofmachines$a.txt")) {
      Write-Host "File C:\users\ka1\documents\listofmachines$a.txt not Found"
      exit
    }
    $comps = gc "C:\users\ka1\documents\listofmachines$a.txt"
  }
  if (-not($a)) {
    if (-not(Test-Path "C:\users\ka1\documents\listofmachines.txt")) {
      Write-Host "File C:\users\ka1\documents\listofmachines.txt not Found"
      exit
    }
    $comps = gc "C:\users\ka1\documents\listofmachines.txt"
  }
  return $comps
}
```

This `getcomputer` function is called in the first PowerShell here:

```bsh
$sccmexe ="C:\Program Files (x86)\SCCM Remote Control Toolset\CmRcViewer.exe" 
$ScriptName = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name
Write-Host $ScriptName
$a = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please type the computername (or Enter for list)'
getcomputer $a

foreach ($computer in $computers) {
  if ((Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 1 -Quiet) -eq $true) {
    & $sccmexe $computer
  } else {
    Write-Host "$computer offline"
  }
}
```

What I am looking to do seems simple, just return the pipeline `$Comps` (so I can process computers) to the main script. Should I keep it `$a` and no change it to `$comps`?

Comment: Looking at the code it's not clear how you want to use it and why you can't just `return $comp`. Also {} braces are unbalanced, indentation is misleading. It'd be helpful if you reduce the code to a relevant minimum ([MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Comment: I would love to use return $comp but it does not seem to return the pipeline. I am sure I am not getting something. This code grabs the listofmachinesx.txt that I am working with. If listofmachinesa.txt exists it will load all the machines and to what I have coded.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell functions [return](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847760.aspx) all output on the success output stream. Pipelines read the success output stream from their upstream cmdlet or process. All you need to do is change your [`foreach` loop to a `ForEach-Object` loop](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/07/08/getting-to-know-foreach-and-foreach-object/) (change the loop variable to `$_`!) and connect it to `getcomputer` with a pipe:

```
getcomputer $a | ForEach-Object {
  if ((Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -Count 1 -Quiet) -eq $true) {
    ...
  } else {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: This is totally awesome. Exactly what I wanted.